# Codeigniter get existing database connection info

Tags: php, codeigniter, background, codeigniter-3

I want to execute on my exisitng codeingiter project a background  script.

The script will use the very same username, password, database and database host from my **Codeingiter** application. This info I want to be passed as command parameters to my script.

Let me show an example (supposing we are in a model):

```
public function callBackgroundScript()
{
   $db_host='';
   $db_name='';
   $db_user='';
   $db_password='';
   exec("php somescript.php $db_host $db_name $db_user $db_password > /dev/null &");
}
```

On the example above how I will set with the existing connection `($this->db)`theese values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [get_instance](http://henrypeteralbers.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html) class.

```
$instance = &get_instance();
$instance->load->database();
echo $instance->db->hostname;
```

This is how you can retrive the database information.

Comment: If I already have loaded a connection can't I retrieve it by $this->db->hostname ?

Comment: Yeah if you have loaded a connection already you can retrieve the same way. But remember you won't be able to use $this in helper.